# How do I exclude moment.js as a dependency within chart.js if I use parceljs as web application bundler?

Tags: chart.js, momentjs, parceljs

Moment.js has a large file size within chart.js and I don't make use moment.js for my charts. Therefore I would like to exclude this dependency, but I don't know how to do it when I use Parcel as web application bundler.

Part of the problem is discribed here: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4303

Comment: Google it or better still look at their github page, it's been asked many times, like here: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4303

Comment: This particular question has never been asked as far as I know. There are solutions to be found if you would use webpack in your project. I've already been on page you mention. Is it an idea if I add them to the question next time?